# How to remove particular tag(In between characters also) from String?

Tags: java, android

I want to remove the particular tag from a string using `<span class="ref-label">`

**Input String:**

```
  <li class="ref-journal" id="B2">
                           <span class="ref-label">2.</span>
                           <span class="family-name">Vainchenker</span>
                           <span class="given-name">W</span>
                           <!--
                "string-name needs to be defined" -->, <span class="family-name">Kralovics</span>
                           <span class="given-name">R</span>
```

**Note:**

Below string **2.** value will be dynamically changed.

```
   <span class="ref-label">2.</span>
```

value will be dynamically changed.

I want to remove the  `<span class="ref-label">2.</span>`

**Expected Output:**

```
<li class="ref-journal" id="B2">
                               <span class="family-name">Vainchenker</span>
                               <span class="given-name">W</span>
                               <!--
                    "string-name needs to be defined" -->, <span class="family-name">Kralovics</span>
                               <span class="given-name">R</span>
```

Comment: OK, what did you try? Where do you struggle? Show your code!

Comment: *Below string 2. value will be dynamically changed.*. Then what do you want to change ???

Comment: This appears to be [XML](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Markup_Language). Read it using [DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) and delete the tag you want to delete!

Comment: I want to remove <span class="ref-label">2.</span> whole word from a string.

Comment: Still not clear, what exactly, you are expecting.. Are you saying, you want to remove that string from XML ??? Can you show us the expected output ?

Comment: I have added the expected output. Please check

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
final String result = xml.ReplaceAll( "<span class=\"ref-label\">[^<]*</span>", "" );
```

Answer (score 0):

To just modify the String, you can use a regular expression with a wildcard for the value and replaceFirst() or replaceAll(). Having said that, chopping up HTML that way may not be a good idea in some circumstances.